# showing that a group of order $p^n$ has an element of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be prime and let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$. Show that $G$ has an element of order $p$. (Hint: Choose an element $1 \neq a  \in G$ and consider the group $\left<a\right>$. Then find an element of order $p$ in this group.)

Approach: It was already proven that $\left<a\right>$ is a subgroup of $G$, so by Lagranges theorem $\def\ord{\operatorname{ord}}\ord(a)$ divides $|G|$. This implies $\ord(a)\mid p^n$. We can say $p^{n}=\ord(a)k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$, so $p^n/k=\ord(a)$.

$\left<a\right>=\{1_G,a,a^2,....,a^{\ord(a)-1}\}$, so we have to find an $1\leq l \leq\ord(a)-1$ such that $\ord(a^l)=\frac{{p^n}/k}{\gcd({p^n/k},l)}=p$. More specific, we have to find an $l$ such that $\gcd({p^n/k},l)=p^{n-1}/k$

This is my approach. What do you think?

Comment: "Question about orders of groups in abstract algebra" is an uninformative title. 1. of course it's a "question": this is a question and answer site. 2. you could ask thousands of things about the "orders of groups": which thing are you asking? 3. of course it's "in abstract algebra": that is, after all, the domain in which we talk about groups.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any non-identity element $g$, by lagrange's theorem its order is $p^k$ for some $k\leq n$. consider the element $h=g^{p^{k-1}}$ it is not $e$ because $p^{k-1}$ is smaller than the order of $g$.

On the other hand $h^p=(g^{p^{k-1})^p=^{p^k}}=e$. So $h$ is the element we wanted.

Comment: In my version of lagrange's, it divides $p^k$

Comment: The order of the subgroup divides $p^n$, and for prime $p$, the only numbers which divide $p^n$ are $p^k$ where $k\leq n$.

Comment: I think that's a theorem in number theory. Can you point it out somewhere?

Comment: If $ord(a)$ had some other prime factorization, then there would be a prime $q \neq p$ such that $q | ord(a)$. However, if $q | ord(a)$ and $ord(a) | p^k$, then $q | p^k$ which is nonsense since the only prime that divides $p^k$ is $p$. Thus, $ord(a)$ must be of the form $p^k$ for $k\neq n$.

Comment: the only way that can happen is if $q=1$, but $a \neq 1$

Comment: I already proved that by using bezout's lemma

Comment: @Carry on Smiling Need help with this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890778/proof-about-dihedral-groups

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890778/…

Answer (score 1):

Note first that the result as stated is not true, as it fails for $n=0$ (a group of order $p^0=1$ clearly has no element of order$~p$). This is not a big deal as it suffices to add $n>0$ to the hypotheses, but it does point to a strange aspect of the problem statement: what really matters for the conclusion is the *presence of at least one prime factor $p$* in the factorisation of $|G|$ (assumed finite), not the *absence of other prime factors*, which is really all that the given hypothesis states. In fact Cauchy's theorem says that whenever $|G|$ is divisible by a prime number$~p$, there is a element of$~G$ with order$~p$.$\def\ord{\operatorname{ord}}$

This being said, the absence of other prime factors does make the proof easier, since one does not have to go searching for an element whose order contains a prime factor$~p$: *every* element $a\neq e$ will satisfy that property (and such$~a$ exists provided that $n>0$), since its order cannot contain any other prime factors. This is what the hint and application of Lagrange's theorem give; so far your approach is fine.

Where you go somewhat astray is in analysing the situation inside the cyclic group $\left<a\right>$. It is a general fact that in searching for an element of order$~d$, it matters little if one actually finds an element$~a$ whose order is a *multiple* of$~d$: if $\ord(a)=md$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$, then $\ord(a^m)=d$ as one easily checks, and one can take $a^m$ instead of$~a$. Stated differently: a cyclic group of a given order$~k$ contains a cyclic subgroup of *every order dividing $k$* (indeed it contains a unique such subgroup, though that is not used here). Concretely, if your element $a$ has $\ord(a)=p^l$ (the only possibility, since all divisors of $p^n$ are again powers of$~p$) with $l>0$, then $\ord(a^{p^{l-1}})=p^l/p^{l-1}=p$, so the element $a^{p^{l-1}}$ answers the question.

Comment: "the result as stated is not true": [it depends...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283).

Comment: @AnneBauval: Of course, I am well aware that $0\in\Bbb N$ is random event.

Answer (score 0):

The order of $G$ can be more general. See [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Statement_and_proof)